# Integrate Master Data Services into SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, master-data-services

Are there any SharePoint components that allow integration of MDS Data into SharePoint? I am looking for be a web part or an API.

Answer (score 1):

The pageviewer web part will include the web interface.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5734.display-the-master-data-services-web-application-in-sharepoint.aspx